# Debugging Mysql Stored Procedure using TOAD for Mysql

Tags: mysql, debugging, stored-procedures, toad, database-scripts

I installed the freeware version of TOAD for Mysql and tried using it to run and execute a stored procedure in debug mode (procedure tab then right-click on the SP then choose 'Debug'). I placed a breakpoint then run (f11), but nothing happens. (just showing backprocess, no cursor highlight movement on the sp code). Tried playing the step-over, step-into button but no avail.
What was the proper step to debug/trace a Mysql SP on TOAD?

Appreciate your kind help. Thank you.

Comment: I was assuming it wasn't possible, but apparently [vs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/visual-studio-debugger.html) can do this. Which MySQL version?

Comment: I'm using WAMP, Mysql version is 5.7.14.
Do you have a step-by-step to debug Mysql SP under Visual Studio? Does it have other dependencies?

Comment: I'm sure you can read the link and related information just as well as I can.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I used DBForge Studio for Mysql for debugging all my code. This is easiest way for debugging all mysql code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).